# DPM thinks tape drives needs cleaning while info from driver doesn't

Tags: drivers, scdpm, tapedrive

I have a Quantum Superloader 3 directly attached to a backup server running DPM 2012 R2 on Windows Server 2012 R2 fully updated. I have a problem where DPM keeps giving an event ID 3308:
DPM could not reserve the drive resource because one of required drive resources is not online or it needs cleaning or servicing. (ID: 24052)
Looking at the properties of the tape drive in Device Manager the Status tab says the next cleaning is due after 100 usage hours, the Lifetime tells me it’s only had 87 usage hours. Why does DPM think it needs cleaning?

Comment: Are there any blinking lights on the drive itself?

Comment: Don't know what was displaying on the status LCD itself at the time but there's nothing in the logs.